# Caret and coefficients (glmnet)

Tags: caret, glmnet

I am interested in utilizing caret for making inferences on a particular data set. Is it possible to do the following:

1. produce coefficients of a glmnet model I trained in caret. I would like to use glmnet because of the inherent feature selection as I do not believe glm has it?
2. other than the ROC metric, is there another metric that I can utilize to asses fit of the model? Such as adjusted $R^2$?

The purpose of this analysis is to derive some inference on the effects of particular variables, rather than for prediction. I just like the caret package because it's been easy to work with thus far using matrices.

Comment: The [caret package](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/) comes with a series of vignettes (and a JSS paper) that cover most of your questions. Could you indicate what precisely you mean by "derive some inference on the effect of particular variables?"

Comment: Inference via the coefficients. I am reading through Applied Predictive Modeling to learn more about R and model building simultaneously. I had read the vignettes and the pdf, but there are just so many functions that it's hard to keep track of them all. Zach answered my question, however, so I am thankful. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I found the link I give here to give the best answer for extracting the final model coefficients https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079660/extract-the-coefficients-for-the-best-tuning-parameters-of-a-glmnet-model-in-car

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Lets say your caret model is called "model".  You can access the final glmnet model with `model$finalModel`. You can then call `coef(model$finalModel)`, etc.  You will have to select a value of lambda for which you want coefficients, such as `coef(model$finalModel, model$bestTune$.lambda)`.

Take a look at the `summaryFunction` parameter for the `trainControl` function.  It will allow you to specify any function you want to minimize (or maximize, see the `maximize` argument to `train`), given a predictor and a response.

It might be hard to get at adjusted R^2 in this way, but you could probably get R^2 or something similar.

Comment: Thank you, Zach. That was exactly it. Also, I want to thank you for your caretEnsemble package. Please keep up the good work.

Comment: @user2300643 No problem!  I'm glad you're using the package.

Comment: In `caret` version `6.0.78`, best tuned lambda is now: `model$bestTune$lambda`.

Comment: is there a way to get the standard errors of those coefficients?