# Extracting Standard Errors Caret Model

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret, train

I have tuned a glm net model with caret using the train function.  I am trying to extract the coefficients and standard errors of those coefficients for the best tuned model.  Following [this CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67827/caret-and-coefficients-glmnet) I figured out how extract the coefficients.  As such, I use

```
coef <- as.matrix(coef(model$finalModel, model$bestTune$lambda))
```

to extract the coefficients.  However, I cannot figure out how to get the standard errors.  I tried `se.coef` (`se.coef <- as.matrix(se.coef(model$finalModel, model$bestTune$lambda))` from the "arm" library but it threw the following error:

```
Error in as.matrix(se.coef(model$finalModel, model$bestTune$lambda)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘se.coef’ for signature ‘"lognet"’
```

Could anyone add any insight please?  I understand that the se.coef may not work with the train function.  However, is there another way to obtain the standard errors for the coefficients?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you could bootstrap your data? For example:

```
library(caret)
library(boot)

n <- 500L

x1 <- rnorm(n, 2.0, 0.5)
x2 <- rnorm(n, -1.0, 2)
y <- factor(rbinom(n, 1L, plogis(-0.6 + 1.0 * x1 - 0.8 * x2)))

dat <- data.frame(y, x1, x2)

caretMod <- train(y ~ ., 
        data = dat, 
        method = "glmnet",
        trControl = trainControl(method = "CV"))

bootSamples <- boot(dat, function(data, idx) {
            bootstrapData <- data[idx, ]

            bootstrapMod <- train(y ~ ., 
                    data = bootstrapData, 
                    method = "glmnet", 
                    trControl = trainControl(method = "none"),
                    tuneGrid = caretMod$bestTune)

            as.vector(coef(bootstrapMod$finalModel, caretMod$bestTune$lambda))
        }, 100L)

Bootstrap Statistics :
      original        bias    std. error
t1*  0.1771481 -0.0232223436  0.27816559
t2*  0.5062797  0.0101922882  0.11641296
t3* -0.3857333  0.0002638111  0.02492466
```

Comment: This is definitely very helpful.  It certainly provides a good estimate.  Does this mean that there is no std errors stored in the train object like there are coefficients?  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I don't think `glmnet` gives any indications into the standard errors of the coefficients.

Comment: Having done further research, it does appear that bootstrapping is only real way to estimate the std. errors for a penalized regression.  Further, it is unclear how meaningful the std. errors are in this case.  Thank you the help and the code!