# caret - get standard errors of glm model

Tags: r, caret

When estimating a `glm` model with `caret`, using the `summary` function the standard errors are printed out. However, I don't know how to extract these values. I can get the coefficient values with `model[["finalModel"]][["coefficients"]]`, but not the standard errors.

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147701/extracting-standard-errors-caret-model) question is similar but its answer suggest bootstrap. If there is a way to get the standard errors in a direct way, it would be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of approaches.

Either take them directly from the summary object:

```
coef(summary(model))[,2]
```

or calculate them from the covariance matrix:

```
sqrt(diag(vcov(model)))
```